# call a function in vim when opening a file with a specific name ignoring directories (regex as a variable)

Tags: regex, vim

i'm trying to make vim check for the filename of the file it's about to open

```
if @%== .\+"notes.tex"
  highlight done ctermbg=blue ctermfg=white guibg=#292960 guifg=#AAAAAA
  match done /.\+itemize.\+/
endif
```

i'd like this script work on the file notes.tex regardless of the directory. the reason i pu .+ before notes is because i want to match all the preceeding characterrs in the filename

in other words i want if to match "notes.tex" and "../notes.tex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better of using the `expand("%")` function to read the filename, and then using `matchstr()` to check it:

```
if matchstr(expand("%"),"notes\.tex$") != ""
  highlight done ctermbg=blue ctermfg=white guibg=#292960 guifg=#AAAAAA
  match done /.\+itemize.\+/
endif
```

Note the `$` in the `matchstr` statement: so this only matches "notes.tex" if it is at the very end of the string.

The nice this about this approach is that it doesn't care about the slash direction (`\` or `/`) and therefore should be platform independent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can't get it to work. 'if expand("%") == "notes.tex"' works if notes in in the same directory but 'if matchstr(expand("%"),"notes\.tex") 
' doesn't

Comment: Does it work if you add `!= ""` after the matchstr statement? (I have edited my answer to include this. That'll teach me for posting without testing!)

Comment: @kirill_igum If {string} matches {regex} is expressed with `{string} =~# {regex}`. I would write something like `expand('%')[-9:] is# 'notes.tex'` because regex is an overkill here.